# Regex to extract patterns from string

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have this string

```
info <-  "/J TOTAL 7/0                      2|/Y TOTAL 118/0                   12"
```

How can I apply `str_extract_all()` from the `stringr` package with the correct regular expression  to extract them into:

1. Part 1  - a vector of `("J TOTAL 7/0", "Y TOTAL 118/0")`
2. Part 2 - a vector of `("2", "12")`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `strsplit` and `strcapture` instead of `str_extract_all()`

```
x <- strsplit(info, "|", TRUE)[[1]]
strcapture("^/(.*?) +(\\d+)$", x, data.frame(a=character(), b=character()))
#              a  b
#1   J TOTAL 7/0  2
#2 Y TOTAL 118/0 12
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option with creating a delimiter i.e. replace more than 2 adjacent whitespace character with `,` using `gsub` and then read with `read.csv` from `base R`

```
read.csv(text = chartr("|", "\n", gsub("\\s{2,}", ",", info)), header = FALSE)
              V1 V2
1   /J TOTAL 7/0  2
2 /Y TOTAL 118/0 12
```